# Why does std::is_function<F> return false_type when F is deduced?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, type-deduction

Given the following code, where the type `Function` is automatically deduced, I get unexpected results when I assert whether `Function` is a function using `std::is_function<Function>`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Function>
bool test_type(Function&& f)
{
    return std::is_function<Function>::value;  
}

template <typename Function>
bool test_decltype(Function&& f)
{
    return std::is_function<decltype(f)>::value;
}

int f()
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << "is_function<Function>:    " << test_type(f) << std::endl
        << "is_function<decltype(f)>: " << test_decltype(f) << std::endl
        << std::endl
        << "Explicit type:" << std::endl
        << "is_function<Function>:    " << test_type<int()>(f) << std::endl
        << "is_function<decltype(f)>: " << test_decltype<int()>(f) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The results are however (Here: http://ideone.com/Jy1sFA, verified locally using MSVC2013.4):

```
is_function<Function>:    false
is_function<decltype(f)>: false

Explicit type:
is_function<Function>:    true
is_function<decltype(f)>: false
```

I expected `is_function<Function>` to be `true_type` even in the deduced case. To be honest I even expected `is_function<decltype(f)>` to be `true_type` in both cases but alas it is not.

Comment: A reference to function is not a function. It's a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra reference for your type you may use `std::remove_reference`:

```
template <typename Function>
bool test_type(Function&& f)
{
    return std::is_function<typename std::remove_reference<Function>::type>::value;
}

template <typename Function>
bool test_decltype(Function&& f)
{
    return std::is_function<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(f)>::type>::value;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/Rk0vM3)